# Counting number of times an NSSound loops (Swift)

Tags: swift, audio, nssound

As the title suggests, I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of times an `NSSound` loops (or, more accurately, have a function run at the beginning and/or end of each loop). I've looked at all the documentation, but I can't find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I've tried using `func sound(sound: NSSound, didFinishPlaying aBool: Bool)`, but it doesn't seem to trigger after a loop completes. The code:

```
func sound(sound: NSSound, didFinishPlaying aBool: Bool) {
    pbNowPlaying.doubleValue = sound.currentTime
    if aBool == true {
        self.btnPlay.title = NSLocalizedString("titlePlay", comment: "Play")
        self.btnPlay.state = NSOffState
        self.pbNowPlaying.doubleValue = 0
        self.btnPlay.needsDisplay = true

    }
    else {
        Swift.print("Sound Looping")
    }
    self.needsDisplay = true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the didFinishPlaying function?  It is called every time the sound file finishes its clip.

```
optional func sound(_ sound: NSSound, didFinishPlaying aBool: Bool)
```

What about creating a variable that will increase each time the function is called forth?  Something easy that will keep track of a count?  The count is what your looking for correct?

```
var count = 0

func sound(sound: NSSound, didFinishPlaying aBool: Bool) {
pbNowPlaying.doubleValue = sound.currentTime
if aBool == true {
    self.btnPlay.title = NSLocalizedString("titlePlay", comment: "Play")
    self.btnPlay.state = NSOffState
    self.pbNowPlaying.doubleValue = 0
    self.btnPlay.needsDisplay = true

    //Start playing sound again after it has ended.
    count + 1
}
else {
    Swift.print("Sound Looping")
}
self.needsDisplay = true

}
```

Comment: I did, but it only seems to trigger on `sound.stop()`.

Comment: Done. I can't seem to get `aBool` to return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

> loops Property
>
> A Boolean that indicates whether the sound restarts playback when it
>   reaches the end of its content.
>
> Declaration
>
> SWIFT var loops: Bool
>
> OBJECTIVE-C @property BOOL loops
>
> Discussion
>
> When the value of this property is YES, the sounds restarts playback
>   when it finishes and does not send sound:didFinishPlaying: to its
>   delegate when it reaches the end of its content and restarts playback.
>   The default value of this property is NO.

i recommend you **set it to false and restart play 'manualy' when you receive didFinishPlaying**

another option is using **duration** and **currentTime** and calculate number of loops